# UPDATE statement with RETURNING clause in PostgresSQL and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-update, pyodbc

I need to run a query in PostgreSQL to first update a record and then return it. Here's the query:

```
WITH x AS ( 
  SELECT "ID" FROM JOB WHERE "STATE" = 1 LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE JOB y SET "STATE" = 2 FROM x WHERE x."ID" = y."ID"
RETURNING y.*
```

It works fine in PostgreSQL server itself. However, running it in Python with pyodbc does not work.

```
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

It says "No results.  Previous SQL was not a query."

Comment: If you are using postgresql  and python, I recommend psycopg2 (or psycopg2-binary), I believe that if you are using pyodbc you must indicate which driver you are using (or at least that was the case when I tried to connect to a Sybase database)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like cursor.execute can't handle multiple statements...

Either rewrite your queries and do them one at a time or try splitting by ;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857840

Comment: Putting links are frown upon, quote the most relevant part here. Also, how do I split it so that the functionality is remained untouched?